# No component is visible in html page, react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I am a beginner in react, I tried to create a webpage, for this I created a new react app https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app following this link.

Also installed a webpack following this link :

https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/journey-into-react-part-2-creating-your-first-react-app/

First installed react

```
C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo>npm install react --save
my-app@0.1.0 C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo
`-- react@15.5.4
```

Then installed react-demo

```
    C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo>npm install react-dom --save
my-app@0.1.0 C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo
`-- react-dom@15.5.4
```

Then created webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js|.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties',
                        'transform-decorators-legacy']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
};
```

Then installed webpack I get output like this:

```
C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo>npm install webpack webpack-dev-server --save-dev
my-app@0.1.0 C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo
+-- webpack@2.5.1
| +-- acorn@5.0.3
| +-- acorn-dynamic-import@2.0.2
| | `-- acorn@4.0.11
| +-- ajv@4.11.8
| | +-- co@4.6.0
| | `-- json-stable-stringify@1.0.1
| |   `-- jsonify@0.0.0
| +-- ajv-keywords@1.5.1
| +-- async@2.4.0
| | `-- lodash@4.17.4
| +-- enhanced-resolve@3.1.0
| | `-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
| +-- interpret@1.0.3
| +-- json-loader@0.5.4
| +-- json5@0.5.1
| +-- loader-runner@2.3.0
| +-- loader-utils@0.2.17
| | +-- big.js@3.1.3
| | `-- emojis-list@2.1.0
| +-- memory-fs@0.4.1
| | +-- errno@0.1.4
| | | `-- prr@0.0.0
| | `-- readable-stream@2.2.9
| |   +-- buffer-shims@1.0.0
| |   +-- core-util-is@1.0.2
| |   +-- isarray@1.0.0
| |   +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7
| |   +-- string_decoder@1.0.0
| |   `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2
| +-- mkdirp@0.5.1
| | `-- minimist@0.0.8
| +-- node-libs-browser@2.0.0
| | +-- assert@1.4.1
| | +-- browserify-zlib@0.1.4
| | | `-- pako@0.2.9
| | +-- buffer@4.9.1
| | | +-- base64-js@1.2.0
| | | `-- ieee754@1.1.8
| | +-- console-browserify@1.1.0
| | | `-- date-now@0.1.4
| | +-- constants-browserify@1.0.0
| | +-- crypto-browserify@3.11.0
| | | +-- browserify-cipher@1.0.0
| | | | +-- browserify-aes@1.0.6
| | | | | `-- buffer-xor@1.0.3
| | | | +-- browserify-des@1.0.0
| | | | | `-- des.js@1.0.0
| | | | `-- evp_bytestokey@1.0.0
| | | +-- browserify-sign@4.0.4
| | | | +-- bn.js@4.11.6
| | | | +-- browserify-rsa@4.0.1
| | | | +-- elliptic@6.4.0
| | | | | +-- brorand@1.1.0
| | | | | +-- hash.js@1.0.3
| | | | | +-- hmac-drbg@1.0.1
| | | | | `-- minimalistic-crypto-utils@1.0.1
| | | | `-- parse-asn1@5.1.0
| | | |   `-- asn1.js@4.9.1
| | | +-- create-ecdh@4.0.0
| | | +-- create-hash@1.1.3
| | | | +-- cipher-base@1.0.3
| | | | +-- ripemd160@2.0.1
| | | | | `-- hash-base@2.0.2
| | | | `-- sha.js@2.4.8
| | | +-- create-hmac@1.1.6
| | | | `-- safe-buffer@5.0.1
| | | +-- diffie-hellman@5.0.2
| | | | `-- miller-rabin@4.0.0
| | | +-- pbkdf2@3.0.12
| | | +-- public-encrypt@4.0.0
| | | `-- randombytes@2.0.3
| | +-- domain-browser@1.1.7
| | +-- events@1.1.1
| | +-- https-browserify@0.0.1
| | +-- os-browserify@0.2.1
| | +-- path-browserify@0.0.0
| | +-- process@0.11.10
| | +-- punycode@1.4.1
| | +-- querystring-es3@0.2.1
| | +-- stream-browserify@2.0.1
| | +-- stream-http@2.7.1
| | | +-- builtin-status-codes@3.0.0
| | | +-- to-arraybuffer@1.0.1
| | | `-- xtend@4.0.1
| | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31
| | +-- timers-browserify@2.0.2
| | +-- tty-browserify@0.0.0
| | +-- url@0.11.0
| | | +-- punycode@1.3.2
| | | `-- querystring@0.2.0
| | +-- util@0.10.3
| | | `-- inherits@2.0.1
| | `-- vm-browserify@0.0.4
| |   `-- indexof@0.0.1
| +-- source-map@0.5.6
| +-- supports-color@3.2.3
| | `-- has-flag@1.0.0
| +-- tapable@0.2.6
| +-- uglify-js@2.8.23
| | +-- uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
| | `-- yargs@3.10.0
| |   +-- camelcase@1.2.1
| |   +-- cliui@2.1.0
| |   | +-- center-align@0.1.3
| |   | | +-- align-text@0.1.4
| |   | | | +-- longest@1.0.1
| |   | | | `-- repeat-string@1.6.1
| |   | | `-- lazy-cache@1.0.4
| |   | +-- right-align@0.1.3
| |   | `-- wordwrap@0.0.2
| |   `-- window-size@0.1.0
| +-- watchpack@1.3.1
| +-- webpack-sources@0.2.3
| | `-- source-list-map@1.1.2
| `-- yargs@6.6.0
|   +-- camelcase@3.0.0
|   +-- cliui@3.2.0
|   | `-- wrap-ansi@2.1.0
|   +-- decamelize@1.2.0
|   +-- get-caller-file@1.0.2
|   +-- os-locale@1.4.0
|   | `-- lcid@1.0.0
|   |   `-- invert-kv@1.0.0
|   +-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1
|   | +-- find-up@1.1.2
|   | | `-- path-exists@2.1.0
|   | `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
|   |   +-- load-json-file@1.1.0
|   |   | +-- parse-json@2.2.0
|   |   | | `-- error-ex@1.3.1
|   |   | |   `-- is-arrayish@0.2.1
|   |   | +-- pify@2.3.0
|   |   | `-- strip-bom@2.0.0
|   |   |   `-- is-utf8@0.2.1
|   |   +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.8
|   |   | +-- hosted-git-info@2.4.2
|   |   | +-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0
|   |   | | `-- builtin-modules@1.1.1
|   |   | +-- semver@5.3.0
|   |   | `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
|   |   |   +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2
|   |   |   | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.2.2
|   |   |   `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4
|   |   `-- path-type@1.1.0
|   +-- require-directory@2.1.1
|   +-- require-main-filename@1.0.1
|   +-- set-blocking@2.0.0
|   +-- string-width@1.0.2
|   | +-- code-point-at@1.1.0
|   | `-- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
|   |   `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1
|   +-- which-module@1.0.0
|   +-- y18n@3.2.1
|   `-- yargs-parser@4.2.1
|     `-- camelcase@3.0.0
`-- webpack-dev-server@2.4.5
  +-- ansi-html@0.0.7
  +-- chokidar@1.7.0
  | +-- anymatch@1.3.0
  | | `-- arrify@1.0.1
  | +-- async-each@1.0.1
  | +-- glob-parent@2.0.0
  | +-- inherits@2.0.3
  | +-- is-binary-path@1.0.1
  | | `-- binary-extensions@1.8.0
  | +-- is-glob@2.0.1
  | | `-- is-extglob@1.0.0
  | +-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  | `-- readdirp@2.1.0
  |   +-- minimatch@3.0.4
  |   | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.7
  |   |   +-- balanced-match@0.4.2
  |   |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
  |   `-- set-immediate-shim@1.0.1
  +-- compression@1.6.2
  | +-- accepts@1.3.3
  | | `-- negotiator@0.6.1
  | +-- bytes@2.3.0
  | +-- compressible@2.0.10
  | | `-- mime-db@1.27.0
  | +-- debug@2.2.0
  | | `-- ms@0.7.1
  | +-- on-headers@1.0.1
  | `-- vary@1.1.1
  +-- connect-history-api-fallback@1.3.0
  +-- express@4.15.2
  | +-- array-flatten@1.1.1
  | +-- content-disposition@0.5.2
  | +-- content-type@1.0.2
  | +-- cookie@0.3.1
  | +-- cookie-signature@1.0.6
  | +-- debug@2.6.1
  | | `-- ms@0.7.2
  | +-- depd@1.1.0
  | +-- encodeurl@1.0.1
  | +-- escape-html@1.0.3
  | +-- etag@1.8.0
  | +-- finalhandler@1.0.2
  | | +-- debug@2.6.4
  | | | `-- ms@0.7.3
  | | `-- unpipe@1.0.0
  | +-- fresh@0.5.0
  | +-- merge-descriptors@1.0.1
  | +-- methods@1.1.2
  | +-- on-finished@2.3.0
  | | `-- ee-first@1.1.1
  | +-- parseurl@1.3.1
  | +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7
  | +-- proxy-addr@1.1.4
  | | +-- forwarded@0.1.0
  | | `-- ipaddr.js@1.3.0
  | +-- qs@6.4.0
  | +-- range-parser@1.2.0
  | +-- send@0.15.1
  | | +-- debug@2.6.1
  | | +-- destroy@1.0.4
  | | +-- http-errors@1.6.1
  | | `-- ms@0.7.2
  | +-- serve-static@1.12.1
  | +-- setprototypeof@1.0.3
  | +-- statuses@1.3.1
  | +-- type-is@1.6.15
  | | `-- media-typer@0.3.0
  | `-- utils-merge@1.0.0
  +-- html-entities@1.2.1
  +-- http-proxy-middleware@0.17.4
  | +-- http-proxy@1.16.2
  | | +-- eventemitter3@1.2.0
  | | `-- requires-port@1.0.0
  | +-- is-glob@3.1.0
  | | `-- is-extglob@2.1.1
  | `-- micromatch@2.3.11
  |   +-- arr-diff@2.0.0
  |   | `-- arr-flatten@1.0.3
  |   +-- array-unique@0.2.1
  |   +-- braces@1.8.5
  |   | +-- expand-range@1.8.2
  |   | | `-- fill-range@2.2.3
  |   | |   +-- is-number@2.1.0
  |   | |   +-- isobject@2.1.0
  |   | |   `-- randomatic@1.1.6
  |   | +-- preserve@0.2.0
  |   | `-- repeat-element@1.1.2
  |   +-- expand-brackets@0.1.5
  |   | `-- is-posix-bracket@0.1.1
  |   +-- extglob@0.3.2
  |   +-- filename-regex@2.0.1
  |   +-- kind-of@3.2.0
  |   | `-- is-buffer@1.1.5
  |   +-- normalize-path@2.1.1
  |   | `-- remove-trailing-separator@1.0.1
  |   +-- object.omit@2.0.1
  |   | +-- for-own@0.1.5
  |   | | `-- for-in@1.0.2
  |   | `-- is-extendable@0.1.1
  |   +-- parse-glob@3.0.4
  |   | +-- glob-base@0.3.0
  |   | `-- is-dotfile@1.0.2
  |   `-- regex-cache@0.4.3
  |     +-- is-equal-shallow@0.1.3
  |     `-- is-primitive@2.0.0
  +-- opn@4.0.2
  | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
  |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4
  +-- portfinder@1.0.13
  | `-- async@1.5.2
  +-- serve-index@1.8.0
  | +-- batch@0.5.3
  | +-- http-errors@1.5.1
  | | `-- setprototypeof@1.0.2
  | `-- mime-types@2.1.15
  +-- sockjs@0.3.18
  | +-- faye-websocket@0.10.0
  | | `-- websocket-driver@0.6.5
  | |   `-- websocket-extensions@0.1.1
  | `-- uuid@2.0.3
  +-- sockjs-client@1.1.2
  | +-- eventsource@0.1.6
  | | `-- original@1.0.0
  | |   `-- url-parse@1.0.5
  | |     `-- querystringify@0.0.4
  | +-- faye-websocket@0.11.1
  | +-- json3@3.3.2
  | `-- url-parse@1.1.9
  |   `-- querystringify@1.0.0
  +-- spdy@3.4.4
  | +-- handle-thing@1.2.5
  | +-- http-deceiver@1.2.7
  | +-- select-hose@2.0.0
  | `-- spdy-transport@2.0.18
  |   +-- hpack.js@2.1.6
  |   +-- obuf@1.1.1
  |   `-- wbuf@1.7.2
  |     `-- minimalistic-assert@1.0.0
  +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
  | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1
  `-- webpack-dev-middleware@1.10.2
    `-- mime@1.3.4

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

But I cant see the bundle.js generated.

And if I run index.html I cant see anything but only a blank page.

Index.html

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->

<script src="/my-app/src/App.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root') )
export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
    "webpack": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Whats going wrong here? Please help. Thank you..

EDIT : I tried to run the webpack I get errors:

```
C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\Desktop\react-demo>npm run webpack
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! missing script: webpack
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\siddhi jambhale\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-13T05_35_36_577Z-debug.log
```

And bundle.js did not get create when I either installed the webpack or run it.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(
         <App />,
         document.getElementById('root')
       ) `  add this code in index.js

Comment: Included this code in App.js and also included <script src="/my-app/src/App.js"></script> script in index.html still I am getting a blank page@XYZ

Comment: updated new files please check. and why I am not getting bundle.js created?

Comment: `ReactDOM.render` must be in index.js.and import app.js in index,js.And add `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` this in yout html

Comment: As in the webpack config. webpack will create a bundle.js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144109/discussion-between-sid-and-xyz).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the `bundle.js` file in `index.html`, write it like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Reason: Check the `webpack config file`:

```
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
}
```

When you run the `webpack`, it will create a output file `bundle.js` that will contain all the code, you need to include that file in `index.html`.

Comment: I dont have bundle.js in my project.@Mayank Shukla

Comment: you have check webpack.config.js file, you specified the output file name `bundle.js`, `bundle.js` is a file that you don't need to create, it will be created by webpack.

Comment: Webpack will create bundle.js

Comment: It did not get create please check the edited question. @MayankShukla

Comment: do you have any **index.js** file ? because in webpack config you specified `index.js` as the entry point for `webpack`.

Comment: remove this line from app.js file: `ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root') )` and check in the same directory where index.html file is present, bundle.js will get created by webpack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144110/discussion-between-sid-and-mayank-shukla).

Comment: Any update for above issue , facing the same issue in my project also